# Simple search to search database table and display result on same page (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a simple seach that searches the `Store_ID` column in a database table and prints the corresponding `GoLive` date from another column but with v.basic PHP skills I'm struggling.

Here is the search code I'm using:

```
<form name="search" method="get"> 
<input type="text" name="store_num"/> <br />
<input type="submit"  value="submit"  name="submit"/>
</form>
```

And here is the MySQL query that I'm trying to execute:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * 
                               FROM wp_Table_GoLive_Date 
                               WHERE Store_ID = 818");
 foreach($results as $r) {
          echo "<p><b>".$r->GoLive_Date."</b></p>"; 
     }
```

My trouble is that my coding knowledge is limited and I can't seem to pass the input of the search to the mysql. I need guidance on getting the search box input data (which will be a store number) to send to the mysql query in place of the '818'.

Any ideas?

Additional info:

The database table has 3 columns:

ID       Store_ID      GoLive_Date

The output of this query:

```html
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_Table_GoLive_Date WHERE Store_ID = 818");
 foreach($results as $r) {
          echo "<p><b>".$r->GoLive_Date."</b></p>"; 
     }
```

is the corresponding date in the GoLive_Date column:  02/02/2015

Answer (score 3):

The value coming from your form is stored in a superglobal array named `$_GET`  (`$_POST` if method was `POST`). You can simply access that value like

```
echo $_GET['store_num'];
```

But if you have to use any user provided values for databases, you have to take extra care to avoid letting people break your database by inserting malicious code, this is called SQL injection.

You use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for that, WordPress [provides an interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) for you to use them easily. In your case it would be something like

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
           $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_Table_GoLive_Date WHERE Store_ID = %d",
           array($_GET['store_num'])
));
```

Comment: Hi Hanky, when I use the above example it gives me a blank page.

Comment: Did you use the updated code that stores the results in `$results` ?

Comment: I am, yes. Here's what I'm using:   $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
           $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_table_GoLive_Date WHERE Store_ID = %d",
           array($_GET['store_num'])
));
 foreach($results as $r) {
          echo "<p><b>".$r->GoLive_Date."</b></p>";

Comment: Are you sure that the ID you are posting has records in the table? Run this after the loop to see how many rows were returned `echo $wpdb->num_rows`;

Comment: it was some other code that was causing the blank page issue but I've removed that now, I can't get it to output the desired info from the 'GoLive_Date' column though. Are you able to help? Also if you could help me with sanitising it, would be much appreachiated

Comment: Yes we can help can you edit your question to show us what it outputs currently and what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

the solution would be using the isset function.

```
<?PHP 
if((isset($_GET['submit'])){
$yourvariable= $_GET['store_num'];
 //your query to execute
 }
?>

<form name="search" method="get"> 
<input type="text" name="store_num" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

the above checks for if user has submitted the form and if yes runs the query and otherwise continue with displaying the form.

Comment: Hi Pushkar, the problem is that I'm limited to wordpress UI with no access to create pages on the server. All the php code im using has to be put into shortcode tags courtesy of a plugin.

Comment: you can do that on the same page just check using the isset function whether user has eneterd data or not and continue accordingly